# Actions on Google: How To Implement Database & User Entities (Session) using NodeJS

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm looking to have a database which contain the devices data that each user has. When the user connects to the Node server, it will somehow retrieve all the devices names and return it to AoG for the NLB engine recognise those names.

How would I go about implementing this?

My current code is attached below (built from sample code from Google):

---

```js
'use strict';

const util = require('util');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {
  dialogflow,
  Suggestions,
  BasicCard,
  Button,
  SimpleResponse,
} = require('actions-on-google');

const {values, concat, random, randomPop} = require('./util');
const responses = require('./responses');

/** Dialogflow Contexts {@link https://dialogflow.com/docs/contexts} */
const AppContexts = {
  FACT: 'choose_fact-followup',
  CATS: 'choose_cats-followup',
  XXX: 'choose_xxx-followup',

};

/** Dialogflow Context Lifespans {@link https://dialogflow.com/docs/contexts#lifespan} */
const Lifespans = {
  DEFAULT: 5,
};

const app = dialogflow({
  debug: true,
  init: () => ({
    data: {
      // Convert array of facts to map
      facts: responses.categories.reduce((o, c) => {
        o[c.category] = c.facts.slice();
        return o;
      }, {}),
      cats: responses.cats.facts.slice(), // copy cat facts
    },
  }),
});

/**
 * Greet the user and direct them to next turn
 * @param {DialogflowConversation} conv DialogflowConversation instance
 * @return {void}
 */
app.intent('Unrecognized Deep Link Fallback', (conv) => {
  const response = util.format(responses.general.unhandled, conv.query);
  const suggestions = responses.categories.map((c) => c.suggestion);
  conv.ask(response, new Suggestions(suggestions));
});

// redirect to the intent handler for tell_fact
app.intent('choose_fact', 'tell_fact');

// Say a fact
app.intent('tell_fact', (conv, {category}) => {
  const {facts, cats, xxx} = conv.data;
  if (values(facts).every((c) => !c.length)) {
    // If every fact category facts stored in conv.data is empty,
    // close the conversation
    return conv.close(responses.general.heardItAll);
  }
  const categoryResponse =
    responses.categories.find((c) => c.category === category);
  const fact = randomPop(facts[categoryResponse.category]);
  if (!fact) {
    const otherCategory =
      responses.categories.find((other) => other !== categoryResponse);
    const redirect = otherCategory.category;
    const parameters = {
      category: redirect,
    };
    // Add facts context to outgoing context list
    conv.contexts.set(AppContexts.FACT, Lifespans.DEFAULT, parameters);
    const response = [
      util.format(responses.transitions.content.heardItAll, category, redirect),
    ];
    // If cat facts not loaded or there still are cat facts left
    if (cats.length) {
      response.push(responses.transitions.content.alsoCats);
    }
    response.push(responses.general.wantWhat);
    conv.ask(concat(...response));
    conv.ask(new Suggestions(otherCategory.suggestion));
    if (cats.length) {
      conv.ask(new Suggestions(responses.cats.suggestion));
    }
    return;
  }
  const {factPrefix} = categoryResponse;
  // conv.ask can be called multiple times to have the library construct
  // a single response itself the response will get sent at the end of
  // the function or if the function returns a promise, after the promise
  // is resolved.
  conv.ask(new SimpleResponse({
    speech: concat(factPrefix, fact),
    text: factPrefix,
  }));
  conv.ask(responses.general.nextFact);
  conv.ask(new BasicCard({
    title: fact,
    image: random(responses.content.images),
    buttons: new Button({
      title: responses.general.linkOut,
      url: responses.content.link,
    }),
  }));
  console.log('hiwwxxxxxww thi is aaron');
  conv.ask(responses.general.suggestions.confirmation);
});

// Redirect to the intent handler for tell_cat_fact
app.intent('choose_cats', 'tell_cat_fact');

// Say a cat fact
app.intent('tell_cat_fact', (conv) => {
  const {cats} = conv.data;
  console.log('this is cats data' + {cats});
  const fact = randomPop(cats);
  if (!fact) {
    conv.contexts.delete(AppContexts.FACT);
    conv.contexts.delete(AppContexts.CATS);
    conv.ask(responses.transitions.cats.heardItAll);
    return conv.ask(responses.general.suggestions.confirmation);
  }
  const {factPrefix, audio} = responses.cats;
  // conv.ask can be called multiple times to have the library construct
  // a single response itself. The response will get sent at the end of
  // the function or if the function returns a promise, after the promise
  // is resolved.
  const sound = util.format(audio, random(responses.cats.sounds));
  conv.ask(new SimpleResponse({
    // <speak></speak> is needed here since factPrefix is a SSML string
    // and contains audio.
    speech: `<speak>${concat(factPrefix, sound, fact)}</speak>`,
    text: factPrefix,
  }));
  conv.ask(responses.general.nextFact);
  conv.ask(new BasicCard({
    title: fact,
    image: random(responses.cats.images),
    buttons: new Button({
      title: responses.general.linkOut,
      url: responses.cats.link,
    }),
  }));
  console.log('hiwwxxxxxww thi is aaron');
  conv.ask(responses.general.suggestions.confirmation);
});



//say a tv channel
app.intent('volume', (conv, {device_name,device_action, value}) => {

  var no_device_name = device_name;
  var no_value = value;
  var no_device_action = device_action;

  var this_device_value = util.inspect(value, false, null);
  var this_device_name = util.inspect(device_name, false, null);
  var this_device_action = util.inspect(device_action, false, null);
  console.log(this_device_action[0]);

  if (no_device_name[0] == 'channel'){
    console.log('inside tv but CHANNEL');



  }

  else{
    console.log('VOLUME');
  }
  console.log('THIS IS VOL');
  console.log(no_device_action[0]);
   conv.ask(`Alright, ${device_name} VOLUM is now ${value}! `);
  console.log('inside volume ' + value[0]);
  console.log('inside volume' + device_name[0]);
  console.log('inside volume' + device_action[0]);
  console.log('hiwwxxxxxww thi is aaron');


});

//say a tv channel
app.intent('channel', (conv, {device_channel_name, device_channel_action, channel_value}) => {


  console.log('THIS IS CHANNEL');



  conv.ask(`Alright, ${device_channel_name} CHANNEL is now ${channel_value}! `);
  console.log('inside CHANNEL ' + channel_value[0]);
  console.log('inside CHANNEL' + device_channel_name[0]);
  console.log('inside CHANNEL' + device_channel_action[0]);
  console.log('hiwwxxxxxww thi is aaron');


});



app.intent('no_input', (conv) => {
  const repromptCount = parseInt(conv.arguments.get('REPROMPT_COUNT'));
  if (repromptCount === 0) {
    conv.ask(`What was that?`);
  } else if (repromptCount === 1) {
    conv.ask(`Sorry I didn't catch that. Could you repeat yourself?`);
  } else if (conv.arguments.get('IS_FINAL_REPROMPT')) {
    conv.close(`Okay let's try this again later.`);
  }
});



// The entry point to handle a http request
exports.factsAboutGoogle = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: I understand that there is conv.user.storage. However, I'm not sure if this data persists or not. Think a database in the node server is more suitable.

Comment: user storage persists for a given user

Answer (score 0):

`conv.user.storage` is supposed to persist for up to 30 days of non-use, indefinitely for regular use, and pretty much linked to the relevant 'Google account', across devices. Note the user can also FORCIBLY disassociate themselves from the data manually (via the assistant app, if they dig into options to find your app).
All that as described here at the time of writing:
https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/user-info

`conv.user.id` seems to remain constant similarly - So could be used to 'key' into an external database if you want to do that.

But you might as well just use userStorage - It seems to have the same lifespan and reliability as the user.id key anyway, and saves you hassle/latency of hitting a DB.

As far as I can tell, if you want a more reliable mechanism than this, then Account Linking is the only other way to go. I will leave you to dig into that yourself...

Comment: Hi @spechter, do you have any idea how to create an User Entity for each user.

Theres this url from the docs: https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/{parent=projects//agent/sessions/}/entityTypes

Comment: @aarontzk - No, sorry, I haven't explored the User Entity functionality. I'd say that's a Dialogflow question. I suggest you ask a separate question on SO.